# Updating hidden input depending on what user has checked

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I've created a test system that has multiple steps (using jquery) allowing users to check checkboxes to select their answers, with a summary page and a final submission button... all within a form. I now want to create the scoring system.

1) Firstly this is the code (within a loop) that grabs the answers from Wordpress for each question:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answer<?php echo $counter; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $row['answer']; ?>" />
```

2) In Wordpress next to each answer is a dropdown with a yes or no option to mark whether the answer is right or wrong. This is output in the following way:

```
<?php $row['correct']; ?>
```

3) Each correct answer the user checks should be worth 1 point. The passmark is determined by the field:

```
<?php the_field('pass_mark'); ?>
```

4) I want it to update a hidden field with the score as the user checks the correct answer:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $score; ?>" name="test-score" />
```

**How can I update the hidden field with the user score as the user is checking the correct answer? I'm not sure what to try with this to even give it a go first!**

---

Ok, everyones spotted a big hole in this. I'm completely open to doing it a hidden way so people can't check out the source. The type of user this is targeted at wouldn't have a clue how to look at the source but might as well do it the right way to start with!

The whole test is within a form so could it only update the hidden field on submit?

I still need some examples of how to do it.

Comment: Wouldn't the user be able to cheat this way? He could easily check out the input to see if he got the points.

Comment: `$('#test-score').val('10');` assuming the input had an id="test-score". Is this what you're looking for? You should definitely do some server side validation to make sure they're not cheating.

Comment: Checking the page source I think could be hardly protected

Comment: Is this a one-time use?

Comment: Ok, everyones spotted a big hole in this. I'm completely open to doing it a hidden way so people can't check out the source. The type of user this is targeted at wouldn't have a clue how to look at the source but might as well do it the right way to start with!

Answer (score 0):

Spokey is right - the user would be able to cheat if your score it on the client side like using the method you suggested.

Instead, either user a JQuery $.post call to post each answer and then store the score in a PHP Session. Or just wait until the entire form is submitted and evaluate the score of the form as a whole on the server side.

*** Update ***

You have to submit the form to a script that can evaluate the form. So say it gets submitted to myForm.php

In myForm.php, get the post vars:

```
$correct_answers = $however_you_get_your_correct_answers(); 

//Assuming $correct_answers is a associative array with the same keys being used in post - 

$results = array();
if($_POST){
   foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
      if ($_POST[$key] == $correct_answers[$key]){
          $results[$key] = 'correct';
      }
      else  $results[$key] = 'incorrect';
   }
}
```

This is untested, but it should work.

Comment: The form calls a mysql insert script and inserts the data (like name, score, test, pass/fail) into a database. If I could score up the test on submit and then enter that score into the database that would be great. Would it be possible for a code example?

Comment: Sure, how are you determining what is correct and what is not correct?Are you manually correcting the form yourself, or do you have the correct answers stored in your database?

Comment: Point 1 in the question loops through the answers. Point 2 shows which one is correct.

Comment: I'm still confused. Where is the actual correct answer coming from? Where are the correct answers stored?

Comment: All the information is stored within Wordpress so that it's just pulling in the data filled within specific fields.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use sessions for that purpose, because any browser output may be saved and viewed in ANY text editor. This is not right purpose oh hidden input elements. You use hidden inputs when you need to submit something automatically, but never use it when processing some important data.

Mapping your questions and answers via `id` will allow you not to reveal real answers and scores in `HTML`.

Just a very simple example how to do that:

```
<?php 
  $questions = array(
    125 => array("text"=>"2x2?", "answer"=>"4", 'points'=>3),
    145 => array("text"=>"5x6?", "answer"=>"30", 'points'=>2),
  );
?>

<form method="post">
  <?php foreach ($questions as $id => $question): ?>
    <div><?php echo $question['text'] ; ?></div>
    <input type="text" name="question<?php echo $id ; ?>"/>
  <?php endforeach ; ?>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>


/* In submission script */
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  foreach($questions as $id => $question){
    if (isset($_POST["question{$id}"])){
      $answer = $_POST["question{$id}"] ;
      if ($answer === $question['answer']){
        $_SESSION['score'] += $question['points'] ;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to do it this way. The tests are dynamic (all added through Wordpress) so there could be hundreds of test with hundreds of questions & answers.